# What is an equivalent replacement for std::unary_function in C++17?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Here is the code that's causing me some issues, trying to build and getting the error:

> 'unary_function base class undefined' and 'unary_function' is not a member of std'

[`std::unary_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) has been removed in C++17 so what is an equivalent version?

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct path_sep_comp: public std::unary_function<tchar, bool>
{ 
    path_sep_comp () {}

    bool
    operator () (tchar ch) const
    {
#if defined (_WIN32)
        return ch == LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ('\\') || ch == LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ('/');
#else
        return ch == LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ('/');
#endif
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::unary_function` has been removed in C++17. You can just remove it - not needed anymore.

Comment: The standard library uses templates for all functions taking callable objects as arguments. You could do the same, and not do any inheritance at all for `path_sep_comp`.

Comment: IIRC, unary_function wasn't *strictly* needed by the standard library before C++17 either. You could have just defined by hand the two aliases it gives you inside your functor. Now those aliases are not required, and as a consequence, neither is unary_function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`std::unary_function` and many other base classes such as `std::not1` or `std::binary_function` or `std::iterator` have been gradually deprecated and removed from the standard library, because there is no need for them.

In modern C++, *concepts* are being used instead. It is not relevant whether a class inherits specifically from `std::unary_function`, it just matters that it has a call operator which takes one argument. This is what makes it a unary function. You would detect this by using traits such as [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) in combination with [*SFINAE*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) or [`requires`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) in C++20.

In your example, you can simply remove the inheritance from `std::unary_function`:

```cpp
struct path_sep_comp
{
    // also note the removed default constructor, we don't need that
    
    // we can make this constexpr in C++17
    constexpr bool operator () (tchar ch) const
    {
#if defined (_WIN32)
        return ch == LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ('\\') || ch == LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ('/');
#else
        return ch == LOG4CPLUS_TEXT ('/');
#endif
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For others finding this SO:
An alternative solution for C++14 and C++17 can be to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of `std::unary_function`. This would ensure that the variables set by `std::unary_function` are set (since `std::function` sets them as well).

Applied to to example from the question that would be:

```cpp
struct path_sep_comp: public std::function<bool(tchar)>
```

However, that might be only a temporary solution as `argument_type`, `first_argument_type`, and `second_argument_type` are removed from `std::function` with C++20.
Thus, a potentially more lasting solution is to to use concepts as suggested by [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63577511/7520239).