# unary_function and binary_function are deprecated in C++ 11, and removed in C++ 17. What should we use instead?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, function-object

I have been reading Effective STL by Meyers.

I came across some sections which mention function adapter objects, such as `not1`, `bind1st`, `bind2nd`. There are apparently a range of such function adapter objects, however I have never encountered these before. Another example is `mem_fun` and `mem_fun_ref`.

Many of these inherit from `unary_function` and `binary_function`. Some links are provided below.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun

These objects are depreciated in C++ 11, which probably explains why I had not encountered them before.

Why are they deprecated, and what replaces them? My instinct tells me that a lambda can replace such function objects, and while reading the book it did occur to me that some of the sorting operations on STL containers can be described using a lambda instead of a function object.

- Does a lambda completely replace these "adapter functions".
- If so, are function objects still useful post C++ 11? If they have been made obsolete in the STL, does this mean function objects are obsolete everywhere in C++ 11 or do they still have uses?

As a final comment, are there any modern books on STL which serve as a good replacement for Meyers Effective STL? I have learned a lot from reading his book but there are probably more sections than I currently realize which contain obsolete information.

Comment: `mem_fun` is replaced with `mem_fn`.

Comment: Duplcate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577103/what-is-an-equivalent-replacement-for-stdunary-function-in-c17

Comment: A minor point on terminology: these things are **deprecated**, not depreciated. No ‘i’.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit asking for book suggestions. Such requests are not appropriate on the site; please don't try to edit that in again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these:

- Lambda expression
- `std::bind`
- `std::mem_fn`

> Does a lambda completely replace these "adapter functions".

Since C++14, lambdas can do everything that the deprecated and later removed functor templates can do.

> If so, are function objects still useful post C++ 11?

Lambdas *are* function objects.

If you mean to ask whether it's still useful to write named function class templates: Yes, it's still occasionally useful.

---

> > Lambdas can be just as reusable by writing a named function that returns the lambda.
>
> Can you add ... an example?

Here's an example:

```
constexpr auto
reusable_lambda() noexcept
{
    return []{
        return "Just an example";
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, my question was whether writing a named function object is useful. I guess "reusability" is the only use case? In other words, not repeating the same block of lambda in several places?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Lambdas can be just as reusable by writing a named function that returns the lambda. The difference is mostly in syntax. Sometimes you need to name the type of the functor, and that's where lambdas are a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I've not seen that before. Can you add a link to a reference or alternatively an example? Again, it isn't something I have come across thus far.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant See the example.

Comment: That's quite interesting. So what is `reusable_lambda`? Is it an object like a class or struct? I guess not because it doesn't have any functions, just some kind of return statement which returns something which looks like a lamba function body. Is this essentially a C++ syntax sugar?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant `reusable_lambda` is a function. It returns a functor. Lambda expression is essentially syntax sugar for a functor.