Migrate away from std::unary _function with tricky signiture
I need to migrate an ancient codebase to support c++17. This means removing auto_ptr, unary_function etc. I've already removed several instances of unary_function successfully but this one is a puzzler.
Here are the prerequisites: Traits macro, RemoveConstRef template.
template <class T>
struct RemoveConstRef {
    typedef T type;
};

#define FPTRAITS_BASIC( _type, _paramType )                                                                            \
    template <>                                                                                                        \
    struct Traits<_type> {                                                                                             \
        typedef _type param_type;                                                                                      \
        typedef _type return_type;                                                                                     \
                                                                                                                       \
        static int fp_param_type() { return _paramType; }                                                              \
        static int fp_return_type() { return _paramType; }                                                             \
                                                                                                                       \
        static param_type get_parameter( FPValue& fpValue ) { return FP_FIELD( _paramType, fpValue ); }                \
        static void get_return_value( FPValue& fpOutValue, return_type val ) {                                         \
            return fpOutValue.LoadPtr( _paramType, FP_RSLT( _paramType, val ) );                                       \
        }                                                                                                              \
    };

FPTRAITS_BASIC( int, TYPE_INT )
FPTRAITS_BASIC( float, TYPE_FLOAT )

...

Original implemenation
template <class T, int Index>
struct get_parameter : public std::unary_function< FPParams*, typename Traits< typename RemoveConstRef<T>::type >::param_type >{
    inline result_type operator()( FPParams* p ) const {
        return Traits< typename RemoveConstRef<T>::type >::get_parameter( p->params[Index] );
    }
};

C++ 17 attempt
template <class T, int Index>
struct get_parameter : public std::function<typename Traits< typename RemoveConstRef<T>::type >::param_type(FPParams*) >{
    inline result_type operator()( FPParams* p ) const {
        return Traits< typename RemoveConstRef<T>::type >::get_parameter( p->params[Index] );
    }
};

These are the compiler errors:

Error C2143: Syntax error: missing ';' before '(' at the operator keyword


You might want to replace RemoveConstRef with std:remove_cv_t and std::remove_reference_t. Or, if C++20 is an option, remove_cvref_t

It'd be good if you show a version of your original pre C++17 code that compiles.

I think you're missing the point of std::unary_function versus std::function. The two are entirely unrelated, and it makes no sense to rewrite get_parameter like you did.
std::unary_function provided argument_type and result_type. With new C++11 features like auto, those typedefs are no longer necessary. Just remove it entirely. The return type of operator() can simply become auto.

std::function is used for type erasure - it can hold many invocable types.

I was following on advice from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577103/what-is-an-equivalent-replacement-for-stdunary-function-in-c17

@BenL: You didn't follow the accepted answer there? You took the quite misleading advice there, and it seems you didn't even apply it as it was probably intended.
